# Laravel Pagination links not including other GET parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pagination, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using Eloquent together with Laravel 4's Pagination class.

**Problem:** When there are some GET parameters in the URL, eg: `http://site.example/users?gender=female&body=hot`, the pagination links produced only contain the `page` parameter and nothing else.

**Blade Template**

```
{{ $users->link() }}
```

There's a `->append()` function for this, but when we don't know how many of the GET parameters are there, how can we use `append()` to include the other GET parameters in the paginated links without a whole chunk of `if` code messing up our blade template?

Comment: you can simply do:
{{ $users->withQueryString()->links() }}
in laravel version 7 and above

Answer (score 144, accepted):

EDIT: Connor's comment with Mehdi's answer are required to make this work. Thanks to both for their clarifications.

`->appends()` can accept an array as a parameter, you could pass `Input::except('page')`, that should do the trick.

Example:

```php
return view('manage/users', [
    'users' => $users->appends(Input::except('page'))
]);
```

Comment: Just to note for other Googlers coming this way - it's now plural `appends`, **not** `append`. The correct chaining would be something like `$query->appends($foo)->links();`

Comment: I found `$query->appends(Input::except('page'))->links();` worked better. Otherwise, the page variable did not update when you clicked a page. Laravel 4.1.24.

Comment: ...and then I scrolled down to see Mehdi's solution.

Comment: Or you can use Input::get() to get all the $_GET vars

Comment: @Benubird Input::get returns all inputt'ed variables, both POST and GET.

Comment: LARAVEL 5:

`{!! $myItems->appends(Input::except('page'))->render() !!}`

Comment: Just for anyone else searching, depending on your implementation it might also look something like this `{!! with(new \App\Presenters\CustomPagerPresenter($results->appends(Input::except('page'))))->render() !!}`

Comment: In laravel 5.2 you should use Request instead of Input

Comment: tested now on laravel 6.2, the use of request global helper more elegant for me.
`{{$items->appends(request()->except('page'))->links()}}`

Comment: Code is written as to use in controller, but Input is a view class... Hassan solution works on Laravel 7, down here:

Comment: Where is the Input? use \Symfony\Component\Console\Input; not work.

Comment: @user2301515 Input no longer exists In larvel 6,7,8 Version. Use Request instead of Input.

Based on the Laravel docs, since version 6.x Input has been removed.

The Input Facade

Likelihood Of Impact: Medium

The Input facade, which was primarily a duplicate of the Request facade, has been removed. If you are using >the Input::get method, you should now call the Request::input method. All other calls to the Input facade may >simply be updated to use the Request facade.

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/class-input-not-found-1?page=1&replyId=656314

Answer (score 160):

I think you should use this code in Laravel version 5+.
Also this will work not only with parameter `page` but also with any other parameter(s):

```
$users->appends(request()->input())->links();
```

Personally, I try to avoid using [`Facades`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) as much as I can. Using global helper functions is less code and much elegant.

**UPDATE:**

Do not use `Input` Facade as it is deprecated in Laravel v6+

Comment: This worked for laravel 5.6, using the accepted answer solution caused an error for me.

Comment: I also implemented this successfully on a 5.3 project; I prefer this simple method as well

Comment: Also, I've noticed that you don't need to use `except('page')` with this solution.

Comment: But what global helper functions but a facades you are trying to avoid?..

Comment: This worked in laravel 8, more useful and simple solution.

Comment: @KorbenDallas `Request` and `Input` fecades

Answer (score 79):

You could use

```
->appends(request()->query())
```

**Example in the Controller:**

```
$users = User::search()->order()->with('type:id,name')
    ->paginate(30)
    ->appends(request()->query());

return view('users.index', compact('users'));
```

**Example in the View:**

```
{{ $users->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```

Comment: This is the suggested way by Mohamed Said (Laravel employee), see: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19441#issuecomment-305526428

Answer (score 50):

Laravel 7.x and above has added new method to paginator:

```
->withQueryString()
```

So you can use it like:

```
{{ $users->withQueryString()->links() }}
```

For laravel below 7.x use:

```
{{ $users->appends(request()->query())->links() }}
```

Comment: Wow its amazing just a single line. I missed the docs. Although 7.x is love

Comment: you provide 2 approaches .Please differentiate them and provide info which one is better and more useful

Comment: @MR_AMDEV  behind the hood both are same. Laravel just adopted it on its latest version.

Comment: @RikeshShrestha Is there a way to urlencode the query parameters with that?

Comment: if you have a blank parameter value  also use if (isset($_GET['search_text'])) {
   
   $search_text = $_GET['search_text'];
  
  } else {
   
   $search_text = "";

  }

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It provides answer for different versions of laravel.

Comment: I'm so confused, I see this in the documentation, and I'm on Laravel 9, but for some reason no matter what parameter I pass as a get parameter it won't be added to the paginated parameter, lets's say I input a parameter ?topic='whatever', then this topic parameter won't be added to the url

Answer (score 41):

**Be aware**  of the `Input::all()` , it will Include the previous `?page=` values again and again in each page you open ! 
for example if you are in `?page=1` and you open the next page, it will open `?page=1&page=2` 
So the last value page takes will be the page you see ! not the page you want to see

**Solution : use `Input::except(array('page'))`**

Answer (score 29):

Not `append()` but `appends()`
So, right answer is:

```
{!! $records->appends(Input::except('page'))->links() !!}
```

Answer (score 11):

**LARAVEL 5**

The view must contain something like:

`{!! $myItems->appends(Input::except('page'))->render() !!}`

Answer (score 11):

In Your controller after pagination add withQueryString() like below

```
$post = Post::paginate(10)->withQueryString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this construction, to keep all input params but page

```
{!! $myItems->appends(Request::capture()->except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Why?

1) you strip down everything that added to  request like that

```
  $request->request->add(['variable' => 123]);
```

2) you don't need $request as input parameter for the function

3) you are excluding "page"

PS) and it works for Laravel 5.1

Answer (score 4):

Include This In Your View 
Page

```
 $users->appends(Input::except('page'))
```

Answer (score 4):

for who one in laravel 5 or greater
in blade:

```
{{ $table->appends(['id' => $something ])->links() }}
```

you can get the passed item with

```
$passed_item=$request->id;
```

test it with

```
dd($passed_item);
```

you must get $something value

Answer (score 3):

In Laravel 7.x you can use it like this:

```
{{ $results->withQueryString()->links() }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass the page number for pagination as well. Some thing like this

```php
$currentPg = Input::get('page') ? Input::get('page') : '1';
$boards = Cache::remember('boards' . $currentPg, 60, function() { 
    return WhatEverModel::paginate(15); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Many solution here mention using `Input`...

**`Input` has been removed in Laravel 6, 7, 8**

Use `Request` instead.

Here's the blade statement that worked in my Laravel 8 project:

```
{{$data->appends(Request::except('page'))->links()}}
```

Where `$data` is the PHP object containing the paginated data.

Thanks to [Alexandre Danault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2446119/alexandre-danault) who pointed this out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159273/laravel-pagination-links-not-including-other-get-parameters#comment122429116_17159349).