# How can I pass extra parameter in pagination by using Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I want apply pagination on laravel 4 by passing extra parameter to filter the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by the **`appends`** method of pagination in laravel.

```
<?php echo $users->appends(array('sort' => 'votes'))->links(); ?>
```

Please use the laravel documentation:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#appending-to-pagination-links

OR

You can go through this link:

[Laravel Pagination links not including other GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159273/laravel-pagination-links-not-including-other-get-parameters)

Look answer of **Bald**.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method signature here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1217
on line no 1385,

The following can be your solution

`paginate($this->limit, $this->fields)`

Thankyou.