# Add parameters to API Resource links in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have many API resources in my Laravel 5.5 app. So far they are great but I am having a problem persisting URL parameters in pagination links.

See the example below
URL: /posts?unreviewed=true

```
    public function getPosts(Request $request){

    /*
     * Gets a list of posts.
     *
     * Options:
     *  - unreviewed: gets posts without revisions (default: false)
     *
     */

    $pagination = 20;

    //Check constrains
    if($request->unreviewed == true){
        return SocialPostResource::collection(SocialPost::with(['images', 'publication.images'])
            ->doesntHave('revisions')
            ->paginate($pagination));
    }

    return SocialPostResource::collection(SocialPost::with(['images', 'publication.images'])->paginate($pagination));

}
```

The example below includes only posts that have been revised. This works perfectly in the first query. The problem is that pagination results do not include the “reviewed=true” parameter in the URL, so page 2 and beyond will return all posts. I need for all URLs to include any parameters passed in the original request.

```
“data”:{...},
“links”:{
   ...
   “next”: “/posts?page=2”
}
```

The result I expect is “/posts?unreviewed=true&page=2”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same problem. In fact, thanks to your question I found [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159273/laravel-pagination-links-not-including-other-get-parameters) that helped me to find a solution that worked in my case.

Please try this:

```
// You must add this Facade in the 'use' section of your file:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

return SocialPostResource::collection(
    SocialPost::with(['images', 'publication.images'])
    ->paginate($pagination)
    ->appends(Input::except('page')) // <- Add this line!
);
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted response. However, do note that "appends" must be placed inside the collection section as shown below:

`return SocialPostResource::collection(SocialPost::with(['images', 'publication.images','brands','products'])
                ->has('brands')
                ->paginate($pagination)
                ->appends(Input::except('page')));`
Diego's response places it outside, which breaks some of the json structure.