# PHP Laravel - keep using the passed paramaters in the url for other urls like pagination links

Tags: php, laravel

I set filters for my customers list:

```
?countries=Germany,France&status=1,3
```

And I have `Previous` and `Next` pagination.

*The following example is in Blade template*

```
@if ($paginator->hasPages())
    <ul class="pagination center" role="navigation">
        {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
            <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span>@lang('pagination.previous')</span></li>
        @else
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" class="page-link" rel="prev">@lang('pagination.previous')</a></li>
        @endif

        {{-- Next Page Link --}}
        @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
            <li><a href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}"  class="page-link" rel="next">@lang('pagination.next')</a></li>
        @else
            <li class="disabled" aria-disabled="true"><span>@lang('pagination.next')</span></li>
        @endif
    </ul>
@endif
```

However, these links do not contain the parameters that were in the url.

What is the best way to save these filters, without saving it to session or cookies because that's not how it should be? or should it?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159273/laravel-pagination-links-not-including-other-get-parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this => `$paginator->appends(request()->query->all())->previousPageUrl();`

Comment: What if I just want to make an url, e.g url("/people/")? I tried url("/people/search/customer", array_merge(request()->all()))}} and it makes my parameters like /germany/ etc and not via params ?countries

Comment: replace array_merge with  `array_replace(Request::all(), ['countries'=>'germany']) )`