# filtering and sorting with pagination in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Hi I'm using Laravel and I have a sorting and filtering system it works via url like this

```
http://localhost:8000/halehule/category/103?type=all&minprice=+10+&maxprice=+10000000000+&color=&sortBy%5Bfield%5D=price&sortBy%5BorderBy%5D=desc
```

so when I use pagination it does not work and refresh to original page like this :

```
http://localhost:8000/halehule/category/103?page=2
```

How can I use pagination with sorting and filtering like this

here is my method

```
public function brandProduct($shop, $id, Request $request) {

  $colors = Color::all();
  $shop = Shop::where('english_name', $shop)->first();
  $shopTags = $shop->tags;
  $shopCategories = $shop->ProductCategories()->get();
  $categories = Shop::where('english_name', $shop->english_name)->first()->ProductCategories()->get()->where('parent_id', null);
  $brand = Brand::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
  $brands = $shop->brands;
  $shopProducts = $shop->products;
  $minPriceProduct = $shopProducts->min('price');
  $maxPriceProduct = $shopProducts->max('price');
  //color product and category product merging
  if($request->color == null){
    $colorAndBrandProducts = $brand->products->sortByDesc('created_at');
  }
  else{
    $colorProducts = Color::where('code', $request->color)->get()->first()->products;
    $brandProducts = $brand->products;
    $colorAndBrandProducts = collect();
    foreach($colorProducts->toBase()->merge($brandProducts)->groupBy('id') as $allProducts){
    if($allProducts->count() > 1){
      $colorAndBrandProducts[] = $allProducts;
          }
    }
  $colorAndBrandProducts = $colorAndBrandProducts->first();
  }
  if ($request->has('type') and $request->has('sortBy') and $request->has('minprice') and $request->has('maxprice') and $request->has('color')) {
    if($colorAndBrandProducts != null){
      $minPrice = $request->minprice;
      $maxPrice = $request->maxprice;
      $filterBy = $request->type;
      $sortBy = $request->sortBy['field'];
      $perPage = 16;
      if($shop->template->folderName == 2){
        $sortBy_array = explode('|', $request->sortBy['field']);
        $sortBy = $sortBy_array[0];
        $orderBy = $sortBy_array[1];
      }
      else{
        $orderBy = $request->sortBy['orderBy'];
      }
      if ($request->type == 'all') {
          if ($orderBy == 'desc') {

              $products = $colorAndBrandProducts->whereBetween('price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])->sortByDesc($sortBy)->unique('id');
          } else {

              $products = $colorAndBrandProducts->whereBetween('price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])->sortBy($sortBy)->unique('id');
          }
      } else {
          if ($orderBy == 'desc') {
              $products = $colorAndBrandProducts->where('type', $filterBy)->whereBetween('price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])->sortByDesc($sortBy)->unique('id');
          } else {
              $products = $colorAndBrandProducts->where('type', $filterBy)->whereBetween('price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice])->sortBy($sortBy)->unique('id');
          }
      }
  }
  else{
    $products = collect();
  }
}
else {
      $products = $colorAndBrandProducts;
  }
  $total = $products->count();
  $perPage = 16; // How many items do you want to display.
  $currentPage = request()->page; // The index page.
  $productsPaginate = new LengthAwarePaginator($products->forPage($currentPage, $perPage), $total, $perPage, $currentPage);
  $template_folderName = $shop->template->folderName;
  SEOTools::setTitle($shop->name . ' | ' . $brand->name);
  SEOTools::setDescription($shop->description);
  SEOTools::opengraph()->addProperty('type', 'website');

  return view("app.shop.$template_folderName.layouts.partials.products", compact('products','minPriceProduct', 'maxPriceProduct', 'shopCategories', 'brand', 'shop', 'categories', 'productsPaginate', 'brands', 'shopTags','colors'));
  }
```

I use this method for sorting and filtering and use pagination works great but without sorting and filtering

Comment: Please show the code you have in your controller.

Comment: Try appending the extra query parameters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159273/laravel-pagination-links-not-including-other-get-parameters

Answer (score 0):

just apply ->append($_GET) to your pagination

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).