# Laravel Pagination Remoing Get URL Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, database

I have a table users where I am getting user specefic data in table

```
abc.com?country=india&state=haryana
```

and I am using Laravel pagination

```
($user->links())
```

when I move to next page previous parameters are removing from the URL. The url only remaining with

```
abc.com?page=2
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Pagination links not including other GET parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159273/laravel-pagination-links-not-including-other-get-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`withQueryString`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) method on the paginator instance.

```
$users->withQueryString()->links()
```

That method is only available as of `Laravel 7`.